# Html decode with prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

is there an Html decode methode with prototype?

I want to translate html code `&#233;` in é but for all the cases.

Comment: prototype? you mean Prototype.js?

Comment: @epascarello Yes I mean.

Comment: Did you get your question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's called unescapeHTML

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/String/prototype/unescapeHTML/

There's also the built in "unescape" in JavaScript.  I'm not sure what the difference is.  I have a feeling unescapeHTML is just calling the built in function.

Comment: Prototypejs: `unescapeHTML()` is only converting <, > and & from its entities.

Comment: Built-in javascript function unescape does URL-decoding (%20 -> ' ').

Answer (score 0):

For standard HTML entities you can use the [unescapeHTML()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/unescapeHTML) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script [HTML Encode](http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode).

```
var decoded = Encoder.htmlDecode('&#233;'); // é
```

Answer (score 0):

Or let the browser do this work: write the encoded string into a `<textarea>` and retrieve its value.

See [Code Example](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post658228.html#post658228).